# What is the effect of ageing on preconsolidation pressure?

Tags: civil-engineering, geotechnical-engineering, soil, soil-mechanics

> Preconsolidation pressure is the maximum effective vertical overburden stress that a particular soil sample has sustained in the past.

How far in the past does the soil remember its loading/the pressure it sustained?

In other words, suppose that at a certain time the Preconsolidation pressure of a soil is $p_0$ due to certain load it had bore in the past. Then does the Preconsolidation pressure $p_0$ changes as the time passes given that the soil is left undistrubed?

Comment: Brilliant question and I suspect that given sufficient time the upper layers will revert like a sponge to near original state less pore size compaction. It's probably related to particle movement due to mechanical or chemical changes in the ground itself.